# Regex to match [integer][colon][alphanum][colon][integer]

Tags: regex

I am attempting to match a string formatted as [integer][colon][alphanum][colon][integer]. For example, 42100:ZBA01:20. I need to split these by colon...

I'd like to learn regex, so if you could, tell me what I'm doing wrong:
This is what I've been able to come up with...

```
^(\d):([A-Za-z0-9_]):(\d)+$
^(\d+)$ 
^[a-zA-Z0-9_](:)+$
^(:)(\d+)$
```

At first I tried matching parts of the string, these matching the entire string. As you can tell, I'm not very familiar with regular expressions.

EDIT: The regex is for input into a desktop application. I'm was not certain what 'language' or 'type' of regex to use, so I assumed .NET . 
I need to be able to identify each of those grouped characters, split by colon. So Group #1  should be the first integer, Group #2 should be the alphanumeric group,  Group #3 should be an integer (ranging 1-4).

Thank you in advance,

Darius

Comment: Sorry about the semi-colons, that was a change I had made. Post updated.

Comment: and you need to specify the language you are using..regex implementation differs across languages

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume the semicolons (`;`) are meant to be colons (`:`)? All right, a bit of the basics.

- `^` matches the beginning of the input. That is, the regular expression will only match if it finds a match at the start of the input.
- Similarly, `$` matches the end of the input.

`^(\d+)$` will match a string consisting *only* of *one or more* numbers. This is because the match needs to start at the beginning of the input and stop at the end of the input. In other words, the whole input needs to match (not just a part of it). The `+` denotes *one or more* matches.

With this knowledge, you'll notice that `^(\d):([A-Za-z0-9_]):(\d)+$` was actually very close to being right. This expression indicates that *the whole input* needs to match:

1. one digit;
2. a colon;
3. one word character (or an alphanumeric character as you call it);
4. a colon;
5. one or more digits.

The problem is clearly in 1 and 3. You need to add a `+` quantifier there to match *one or more* times instead of just once. Also, you want to place these quantifiers *inside the capturing groups* in order to get the multiple matches inside one capturing group as opposed to receiving multiple capturing groups containing single matches.

```
^(\d+):([A-Za-z0-9_]+):(\d+)$
```

Comment: Technically, no. But the OP doesn't make it clear exactly what he's looking for.

Comment: @nhahtdh In most variants, it's called a *word character*. Updated my answer for clarity.

Comment: I need to be able to identify each of those grouped characters, split by colon. So Group #1  should be the first integer, Group #2 should be the alphanumeric group,  Group #3 should be an integer (ranging 1-4).

Comment: So Mattias, if I wanted to match ([integer][colon]), literally, as one group, how would I do so?

Comment: @MattiasBuelens: "Word" character and alphanumeric are different.

Comment: @nhahtdh I know, but what the OP is *actually* matching is a word character.

Comment: @Darius If you need to capture the colon *inside* the group, just move it in there: `^(\d+:)([A-Za-z0-9_]+:)(\d+)$`

Comment: @MattiasBuelens: It is a mismatch between his code and his description. I'd usually go with the description, though.

Comment: @nhahtdh I started from his initial code. Either way, you can just remove the `_` from the character group to match only alphanumeric characters. I'd suggest the OP chooses what suits him.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use quantifiers

```
^(\d+):([A-Za-z0-9_]+):(\d+)$
    ^     ^     ^
```

`+` is quantifier that matches preceeding pattern 1 to many times

Now you can access the values by accessing the particular groups

Comment: In some languages, `\w` includes more than simply alpha-numerics (`_` and `-` being two common ones).

Comment: @JonahBishop thanks for the suggestion..edited the ans..stackoverflow should make it compulsory to tag regex questions with language they are using...

Comment: @JonahBishop: Which language include `-`? All that I have seen so far are alphanumeric and `_`.

Comment: I feel like I've seen hyphen included somewhere, but I may be misremembering. I know that Perl will use locale specific characters (variants on the underscore, for example) if the reg-ex is parsing Unicode characters. See [perlrecharclass](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass.html) for more.

Comment: @JonahBishop: I know that some variant when Unicode is activated will start matching connectors (.NET regex). But for ASCII, all I have seen only include alphanumeric and `_`.

Comment: I could have a faulty memory then... It wouldn't be the first time. :)